# how to convert json file in following format{"Description":"Cmd is an open source tool",Data{"Aliases":"xCmd","Software":"xCmd","_raw":""}

Tags: java

```
File input = new File("file1.csv");
File output = new File("output1.json");

CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

// Read data from CSV file
List<Object> readAll = null;
try {
    readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(readAll);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Write JSON formated data to output.json file
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);
```

Comment: Does CsvSchema work on JSON files?

Comment: I used csvSchema to convert csv file into json format but now i want json data in  following format:                                                                                               {
  "Description" : "xCmd is an open source tool",
  Data {
  "Aliases" : "xCmd",  
  "Software" : "xCmd",
  "_raw" : "it is an open source tool",
  "_time" : "2019-10-15T18:05:19.000+0000",
  "eventtype" : "",
  "host" : "splunk",
  "index" : "mitre-software",
  "linecount" : "1",
  "punct" : ",,____________________.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
  "sourcetype" : "software"
  }
}